# no such process error with launchctl start. Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, launchd

The goal is to set machine's network name with the ipaddress of this machine.
I have created a plist file and put it into /Library/Launchagents/. For debugging reason I used the command "launctl start".
Here is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.myfile.hostname</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/ipconfig</string>
    <string>getifaddr</string>
    <string>en0</string>
    <string>|</string>
    <string>/usr/bin/tr</string>
    <string>-d</string>
    <string>'.'</string>
    <string>|</string>
    <string>sudo</string>
    <string>/usr/sbin/scutil</string>
    <string>--set</string>
    <string>LocalHostName</string>
  </array>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/AlTest1.err</string>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/AlTest1.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I use:

```
launchctl start /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myfile.hostname.plist
```

and get the error:

```
launchctl start error: No such process
```

As the error is not explaining what exactly is wrong with that file Im struggling to find the reason. The command itself on the command work fine. If this is the wrong section for this question please advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the launchctl command:

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myfile.hostname.plist`

This will load the job ticket rather than start a named job.

I am not sure pipes are permitted within a launchd job ticket list of arguments. Using them requires the argument to be passed to a shell for interpretation and this may not happen. Consider passing the command directly to `/bin/sh` as a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the leading directories worked for me:

```
sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.bind
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this will solve your problem (I have the same issue) but if you do a:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myfile.hostname.plist
```

It might work.  It did for me.  Maybe a clue as to what's happening.  Maybe not.  Let me know if you fix this issue.  We're all in this together.

Comment: Would this be better as an edit to Graham's answer instead of setting apart? If you want to keep it apart, please elaborate on why sudo is needed in front of the command so that it helps spur discussion and perhaps helps the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are a shell feature and launchd is *not* a shell. Put the command into a shell script instead and make your job call this script. Also get rid of the `sudo` in the script. If you need root privileges store the job definition in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the extension, it should work then.

```
launchctl start /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myfile.hostname
```